# Pratical Socket on windows 7 64bit

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, 64-bit

I've never used the socket in C + +, but now I have to use them on school grounds.

I need to use this

http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/practical/

that is for 32bit system. But I need to build a 64bit application.

I'm on Windows 7 64bit, and searching on this site (and google) I've found that in windows 7 64bit wsock32.lib there isn't and has been replaced with a library called ws2_32.lib.

My problem is: I try to compiling the TCPEchocliend.cpp example file, but Visual C++ 2010 give me this error:

> TCPEchoClient.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno
>   "public: int __thiscall CommunicatingSocket::recv(void *,int)"
>   (?recv@CommunicatingSocket@@QAEHPAXH@Z) non risolto nella funzione
>   _main 1>TCPEchoClient.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: void __thiscall CommunicatingSocket::send(void const
>   *,int)" (?send@CommunicatingSocket@@QAEXPBXH@Z) non risolto nella funzione _main 1>TCPEchoClient.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al
>   simbolo esterno "public: __thiscall TCPSocket::TCPSocket(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &,unsigned short)"
>   (??0TCPSocket@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@G@Z)
>   non risolto nella funzione _main 1>TCPEchoClient.obj : error LNK2019:
>   riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: __thiscall
>   Socket::~Socket(void)" (??1Socket@@QAE@XZ) non risolto nella funzione
>   "public: __thiscall CommunicatingSocket::~CommunicatingSocket(void)"
>   (??1CommunicatingSocket@@QAE@XZ)
>   1>C:\OPENCV\Test\miei\provefunzioni\sockt\Debug\sockt.exe : fatal
>   error LNK1120: 4 esterni non risolti

How can I compile and run under Windows 7 64 bit and Visual Studio 2010 that application in a 64bit project?

Because I have to study that class and member for using them in a my program subsequently, but if I can't compile and use it, It's difficult that I reach that goal.

I have put the ws2_32.lib as "additional dependencies" in Linker-->Input but give me an error...

Sorry for my poor english, thanks in advance to everyone can help me.

Comment: Can't really say for certain; I can only make educated guesses as to what the error messages say (since they're not in English).
But I can see that `TCPEchoClient.cpp` links against `PracticalSocket.cpp` and that includes `winsock.h`. In your case, you should change that to `include <winsock2.h>`.

Comment: It is not complaining about the standard socket functions, it complains about your CommunicatingSocket and TCPSocket classes.  Linking the .lib or .obj file that contains the code for these classes is required.  You cannot learn much from using somebody else's code, write your own.

Comment: Thanks for your time...replace <winsock.h> with <winsock2.h> generate more linker error and compiling error, so remain original. I've found wsock32.lib in my harddisk, linked to project and now compile. So, at least, now I've only to understand how works...